# Propuesta: Preguntas tipo proyecto de adaptación de código ( ¿bifurcación (fork) / reuso?)

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

## Panorama

Considerando que en SOes haremos las cosas diferentes a SO, propongo que se considere incluir en el alcance del sitio proyectos de adaptación de código. Como ejemplo de proyecto de adaptación de código he publicado una pregunta, que trata sobre un proyecto en curso.

[Cómo adaptar evenBetterBuildUrls() de Mogsdad para importar respuestas a un formulario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/753/65)

## Beneficios

Por un lado la utilidad de este tipo de preguntas son:

1. Se comparte la adaptación de un código
2. Se extiende la audiencia, por ejemplo, a usuarios que hablan español.
3. Quien realiza la adaptación podría recibir orientación de otros
4. Quien realiza la adaptación podría recibir comentarios para extender o acotar el alcance de la adaptación con la finalidad de hacer más fácil de adoptar

## Referencias

### Terminología

"adaptación de código" los artículos de Wikipedia que podría corresponder  son

- [bifurcación (fork)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcaci%C3%B3n_(desarrollo_de_software))
- [Code reuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse) (no he encontrado uno en español)
- [adaptability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptability) (el artículo en español es demasiado escueto)
- [refactorización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactorizaci%C3%B3n)

### Artículos

- [Enabling code adaptation by for Non-programmers (pdf)](https://lookingglass.wustl.edu/pdfs/publications/5.pdf)

## Método de investigación

A raíz de un comentario, he puesto en práctica los siguientes métodos de investigación:

### Buscar en Google usando términos en inglés

Búsquedas usando google.com.mx, con inicio de sesión, cuenta con configuración de idioma preferente Español Latinoamérica y en otros idiomas que entiendo Inglés.

- [wikipedia fork]
- [wikipedia code reuse]
- [wikipedia refactoring]
- [code adaptation](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=code%20adaptation)

Comment: No entiendo bien a que te refieres con adaptación de código, podrías explicar un poco más como es diferente de otro tipo de preguntas?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz agregué una sección de terminología con un par de enlaces. Estoy por agregar otro.